# Two different paths in Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I am using smarty in my php project

```
|->app
    |view
        |path_returned_by_handler.tpl
|->lib
    |abstract
        |controller.php
    |view
        |path_to_be_used_by_controller.tpl
```

there are is some handler which returns path to some sub_template but in display I want to use /lib/view/path_to_be_used_by_controller.tpl
and inside this file i will use the path returned by handler like this
{include file="$path_returned_by_handler" title="sub_temp"}

how do i do this?
1) one solution cud be that I use absolute path, and not use setTemplateDir at all or set to top parent directory, and use relative path from there.
any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use relative paths you need to use ./ at the beginning of include

Structure:

```
| index.tpl
  |test
      test.tpl
      test3.tpl
      |test2
           test2.tpl
```

index.tpl

```
{include file="test/test.tpl"}
```

test.tpl

```
I'm test<br />

{include "./test3.tpl"}

{include "./test2/test2.tpl"}
```

test2.tpl

```
I'm test 2<br />
```

test3.tpl

```
I'm test 3<br />
```

Result when displaying index.tpl is:

```
I'm test
I'm test 3
I'm test 2
```

so relative paths in templates work fine. It was tested in the newest Smarty 3.1.18